# Appending two arrays together in Python

Tags: python, arrays, append

I've been working in Python with an array which contains a one-dimensional list of values. I have until now been using the array.append(value) function to add values to the array one at a time.

Now, I would like to add all the values from another array to the main array instead. In other words I don't want to add single values one at a time. The secondary array collects ten values, and when these are collected, they are all transfered to the main array. The problem is, I can't simply use the code 'array.append(other_array)', as I get the following error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `array.append(other_array)` will never lead to the cited error message.  Please show your real code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are looking for [array.extend()](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#array.array.extend) method. `append()` only appends a single element to the array.

Answer (score 30):

Lists can be added together:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [5,6,7,8]
>>> a+b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

and one can be easily added to the end of another:

```
>>> a += b
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: The question was about array, not list.

Answer (score 2):

Array (as in `numpy.array` or `array` module) or `list`? Because given your error message, it seems the later.

Anyway, you can use the `+=` operator, that should be overridden for most container types, but the operands must be of the same (compound) type.

Comment: The += will add the values, it does not affect the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you want to expand a structure to the right (`axis=1`) or at the bottom (`axis=0`), you should have a look at the `numpy.concatenate()` function, see [Concatenate a NumPy array to another NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775297/concatenate-a-numpy-array-to-another-numpy-array).

```
np.concatenate(arr1, arr2, axis=0)
```

is probably what is needed here, adding a new row in a nested array.