# Concatenate a NumPy array to another NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy_array. Something like `[ a b c ]`.

And then I want to concatenate it with another NumPy array (just like we create a list of lists). How do we create a NumPy array containing NumPy arrays?

I tried to do the following without any luck

```
>>> M = np.array([])
>>> M
array([], dtype=float64)
>>> M.append(a,axis=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: You can create an "array of arrays" (you use an object array), but you almost definitely don't want to.  What are you trying to do?  Do you just want a 2d array?

Comment: An array of arrays is called a nested array. Three answers in this thread are about np.append() which does not keep the nested structure. This is because of a question without a clear example.

Answer (score 292, accepted):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

In [3]: b = np.array([[9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4]])

In [4]: np.concatenate((a, b))
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [9, 8, 7],
       [6, 5, 4]])
```

or this:

```
In [1]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

In [2]: b = np.array([4, 5, 6])

In [3]: np.vstack((a, b))
Out[3]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: Hi when i run this i get this np.concatenate((a,b),axis=1)
Output: array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4])
But what I looking for is numpy 2d array??

Comment: @Fraz: I've added Sven's `vstack()` idea.  You know you can create the array with `array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])`, right?

Comment: concatenate() is the one I needed.

Comment: [`numpy.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) can accept more than 2 arrays in the sequence argument. Thus if you need to combine more than 2 arrays, vstack is more handy.

Comment: @oneleggedmule `concatenate` can also take multiple arrays

Comment: When i try to concatenate i get a single dimension array instead of 2.

Comment: @user12067965 are you sure you're using the double parens... ie `concatenate((` vs`concatenate(`

Answer (score 95):

Well, the error message says it all:  NumPy arrays do not have an `append()` method.  There's a free function [`numpy.append()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) however:

```
numpy.append(M, a)
```

This will create a new array instead of mutating `M` in place.  Note that using `numpy.append()` involves copying both arrays.  You will get better performing code if you use fixed-sized NumPy arrays.

Comment: Hi.. when i try this.. I get this
>>> np.append(M,a)
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])
>>> np.append(M,b)
array([ 2.,  3.,  4.])
>>> M
array([], dtype=float64)
I was hoping M to be a 2D array??

Comment: @Fraz: Have a look at `numpy.vstack()`.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer as it precisely answers to the point.

Comment: This answer does not fit to the question. It just makes a flattened array out of any structure you put in. For example for `np.append(arr1,arr2)` with arr1 and arr2 being 3x3 arrays, the output structure is 1x18: `array([1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])`. Which is not what was asked for, instead, a nested array was asked for.

Answer (score 39):

You may use `numpy.append()`...

```
import numpy

B = numpy.array([3])
A = numpy.array([1, 2, 2])
B = numpy.append( B , A )

print B

> [3 1 2 2]
```

This will not create two separate arrays but will append two arrays into a single dimensional array.

Comment: A nested array was asked for, not a flattened array.

Answer (score 10):

I found this link while looking for something slightly different, how to start appending array objects to an **empty** numpy array, but tried all the solutions on this page to no avail.

Then I found this question and answer: [How to add a new row to an empty numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392497/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-an-empty-numpy-array)

The gist here:

> The way to "start" the array that you want is:
>
> `arr = np.empty((0,3), int)`

Then you can use concatenate to add rows like so:

`arr = np.concatenate( ( arr, [[x, y, z]] ) , axis=0)`

See also https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Comment: That's what I ended up having to use but it does seem rather a kludge.

Answer (score 9):

Sven said it all, just be very cautious because of automatic type adjustments when append is called.

```
In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: a = np.array([1,2,3])

In [4]: b = np.array([1.,2.,3.])

In [5]: c = np.array(['a','b','c'])

In [6]: np.append(a,b)
Out[6]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  2.,  3.])

In [7]: a.dtype
Out[7]: dtype('int64')

In [8]: np.append(a,c)
Out[8]: 
array(['1', '2', '3', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

As you see based on the contents the dtype went from int64 to float32, and then to S1

Comment: A nested array was asked for.

Answer (score 8):

Actually one can always create an ordinary list of numpy arrays and convert it later.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

In [3]: b = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

In [4]: l = [a]

In [5]: l.append(b)

In [6]: l = np.array(l)

In [7]: l.shape
Out[7]: (2, 2, 2)

In [8]: l
Out[8]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and I couldn't comment on @Sven Marnach answer (not enough rep, gosh I remember when Stackoverflow first started...) anyway.

Adding a list of random numbers to a 10 X 10 matrix.

```
myNpArray = np.zeros([1, 10])
for x in range(1,11,1):
    randomList = [list(np.random.randint(99, size=10))]
    myNpArray = np.vstack((myNpArray, randomList))
myNpArray = myNpArray[1:]
```

Using np.zeros() an array is created with 1 x 10 zeros.

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Then a list of 10 random numbers is created using np.random and assigned to randomList.
The loop stacks it 10 high. We just have to remember to remove the first empty entry.

```
myNpArray

array([[31., 10., 19., 78., 95., 58.,  3., 47., 30., 56.],
       [51., 97.,  5., 80., 28., 76., 92., 50., 22., 93.],
       [64., 79.,  7., 12., 68., 13., 59., 96., 32., 34.],
       [44., 22., 46., 56., 73., 42., 62.,  4., 62., 83.],
       [91., 28., 54., 69., 60., 95.,  5., 13., 60., 88.],
       [71., 90., 76., 53., 13., 53., 31.,  3., 96., 57.],
       [33., 87., 81.,  7., 53., 46.,  5.,  8., 20., 71.],
       [46., 71., 14., 66., 68., 65., 68., 32.,  9., 30.],
       [ 1., 35., 96., 92., 72., 52., 88., 86., 94., 88.],
       [13., 36., 43., 45., 90., 17., 38.,  1., 41., 33.]])
```

So in a function:

```
def array_matrix(random_range, array_size):
    myNpArray = np.zeros([1, array_size])
    for x in range(1, array_size + 1, 1):
        randomList = [list(np.random.randint(random_range, size=array_size))]
        myNpArray = np.vstack((myNpArray, randomList))
    return myNpArray[1:]
```

a 7 x 7 array using random numbers 0 - 1000

```
array_matrix(1000, 7)

array([[621., 377., 931., 180., 964., 885., 723.],
       [298., 382., 148., 952., 430., 333., 956.],
       [398., 596., 732., 422., 656., 348., 470.],
       [735., 251., 314., 182., 966., 261., 523.],
       [373., 616., 389.,  90., 884., 957., 826.],
       [587., 963.,  66., 154., 111., 529., 945.],
       [950., 413., 539., 860., 634., 195., 915.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, here's one way.  Say you have:

```
a = [4.1, 6.21, 1.0]
```

so here's some code...

```
def array_in_array(scalarlist):
    return [(x,) for x in scalarlist]
```

Which leads to:

```
In [72]: a = [4.1, 6.21, 1.0]

In [73]: a
Out[73]: [4.1, 6.21, 1.0]

In [74]: def array_in_array(scalarlist):
   ....:     return [(x,) for x in scalarlist]
   ....: 

In [75]: b = array_in_array(a)

In [76]: b
Out[76]: [(4.1,), (6.21,), (1.0,)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for people working with `numpy's ndarrays`. The function `numpy.concatenate()` does work as well.

```
>>a = np.random.randint(0,9, size=(10,1,5,4))
>>a.shape
(10, 1, 5, 4)

>>b = np.random.randint(0,9, size=(15,1,5,4))
>>b.shape
(15, 1, 5, 4)

>>X = np.concatenate((a, b))
>>X.shape
(25, 1, 5, 4)
```

Much the same way as `vstack()`

```
>>Y = np.vstack((a,b))
>>Y.shape
(25, 1, 5, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to concatenate along an existing axis (row wise), `np.vstack` or `np.concatenate` will work for you.

**For a detailed list of concatenation operations, refer to the [official docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#joining-arrays).**

Answer (score 0):

There is a handfull of method to stack arrays together, depending on the direction of the stack.
You may consider np.stack() ([doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html)), np.vstack() ([doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)) and np.hstack() ([doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)) for example.