# Python adding records to an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array defined as -

```
import numpy as np
A = np.recarray((3,),dtype=[('x',float), ('y', float), ('z',float)])
```

Plus another array B which is read from a CSV file as -

```
>>> print B
[(7.0, 0.0, 7.0) (16.0, 0.0, 1.0)]
```

When I try to add the elements to array as given below -

```
for i in range(B.size):
    if(B[i][0] != 0.):
        A.append((0.,B[i][1],B[i][2]))
    if(B[i][1] != 0.):
        A.append((B[i][0],0.,B[i][2]))
    if(B[i][2] != 0.):
        A.append((B[i][0],B[i][1],0.))
```

I get an error as follows -

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/records.py", line 416, in __getattribute__
    raise AttributeError, "record array has no attribute %s" % attr
    AttributeError: record array has no attribute append
```

I am not able to understand where does this string attribute (%s) is coming into picture?

Can someone help out please?

**UPDATE:**
I changed the code to `np.append(A,(0.,B[i][1],B[i][2]))`, however I get another error as - `TypeError: invalid type promotion`

Comment: "%S" is just showing the stacktrace.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775297/append-a-numpy-array-to-a-numpy-array (and probably others) there is `numpy.append`, but its usually not the best solution.

Comment: Actually, since these are recarrays, there might be some more details involved when concatenating (`np.lib.recfunctions.stack_arrays` may help in that case), but that should be no problem if the fields are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending to a numpy array is a slow operation because new memory has to be allocated and the entire array has to be copied. Doing this for each row of `B` would be inefficient. Avoid this if you can.

If you know the shape of `A` and `minors(B)` (see below) in advance, it is best to make an array which is big enough to accomodate both from the beginning.

There are many was to do what you asking. @seberg's `np.lib.recfunctions.stack_arrays` idea would make a viable solution as long as the dtypes of `A` and `B` are the same.

Here is another possibility, which will work even if `B` has a different dtype, or is just a ndarray or list of lists.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

def minors(arr):
    for row in arr:
        row = list(row)
        for i, elt in enumerate(row):
            if elt != 0:
                for val in row[:i]+[0]+row[i+1:]:
                    yield val

A = np.recarray((3,),dtype=[('x',float), ('y', float), ('z',float)])
B = [(7.0, 0.0, 7.0), (16.0, 0.0, 1.0)]

C = np.fromiter(itertools.chain(A.view(float), minors(B)), dtype = float)
C = C.view(A.dtype)
```

Comment: your code gave me an answer like this - `>>> print C
[(3.1310608122305046e-307, -3.263691770160412e-42, -3.2646770584641245e-42)
 (-3.2646770580222135e-42, -1.1666518207782148e-41, -1.086168727138965e-41)
 (-1.1664766582821353e-41, 3.277940205911456e-260, 8.330460061897614e-259)
 (0.0, 0.0, 7.0) (7.0, 0.0, 0.0) (0.0, 0.0, 1.0) (16.0, 0.0, 0.0)]`. I think the first 3 entries are garbage?

Comment: @RajTendulkar `A` is initialized with garbage, that is correct, maybe you are lookng for `A = np.recarray((0,), ...)`. The `np.lib.recfunctions.stack_array` are a generalization for recarrays that can handle different fields, if fields are guaranteed to be completly the same, normal concatenation works.

Answer (score 1):

The error is just saying that recarray does not have any method called append.

I have not really used numpy but one solution could be to convert A into list

```
A.tolist()
```

appending records to this list and then doing something like

```
np.fromiter(x, A.dtype)
```

to get the new recarray. This, of course, does not look like a good solution.

Perhaps someone more familiar with numpy will be able to pitch in and improve it.