# Two Columns of a pandas dataframe - Concat in Python

Tags: python, pandas

New to pandas python.

I have a dataframe (df) with two columns of cusips.
I want to turn those columns into a list of the unique entries of the two columns.

My first attempt was to do the following:

cusips = pd.concat(df['long'], df['short']).

This returned the error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.  Use a.any() or a.all().

I have read a few postings, but I am still having trouble with why this comes up.  What am I missing here?

Also, what's the most efficient way to select the unique entries in a column or a dataframe?  Can I call it in one function?  Does the function differ if I want to create a list or a new, one-coulmn dataframe?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Hayden's answer, you could also use the `set()` method for the same result.  The performance is slightly better if that's a consideration:

```
In [28]: %timeit set(np.append(df[0],df[1]))
100000 loops, best of 3: 19.6 us per loop

In [29]: %timeit np.append(df[0].unique(), df[1].unique())
10000 loops, best of 3: 55 us per loop
```

Comment: set is definitely the way to go here, I am upset it is faster than `numpy.unique` (which sorts)!

Comment: Quick follow-up.  Does Set take all or just the unique of df[0] and df[1].  I am assuming the unique only.

Any thoughts on this:
This returned the error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

What should I make of that?

Comment: Try enclosing your Series in []: cusips = pd.concat([df['long'], df['short']])

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the unique values in a column you can use the [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html#pandas.Series.unique) Series method, which will return a numpy array of the unique values *(and it is fast!)*.

```
df.long.unique()
# returns numpy array of unique values
```

You could then use [`numpy.append`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html):

```
np.append(df.long.unique(), df.short.unique())
```

Note: This just appends the two unique results together and so itself is not unique!

.

Here's a (trivial) example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 4]], columns=['long','short'])

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   long  short
0     1      2
1     1      4

In [5]: df.long.unique()
Out[5]: array([1])

In [6]: df.short.unique()
Out[6]: array([2, 4])
```

And then [appending the resulting two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9775378/1240268):

```
In [7]: np.append(df.long.unique(), df.short.unique())
Out[7]: array([1, 2, 4])
```

Using @Zalazny7's `set` is significantly faster (since it runs over the array only once) and somewhat upsettingly it's even faster than [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) *(which sorts the resulting array!)*.