# How to append numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I want append numpy arrays like below

> ```
> A: [[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[1,4,2]] 
> B: [[1,3,3],[3,3,1],[1,4,5]]
> A+B = [[[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[1,4,2]],
>        [[1,3,3],[3,3,1],[1,4,5]]]
> ```

How can I do this?

====================

Code copied from comment, and formatted for clarity:

```
X = np.empty([54, 7]) 
for seq in train_set: 
    print(seq) 
    temp = dp.set_xdata(seq) #make 2d numpy array 
    print(temp.shape) 
    X = np.row_stack((X[None], temp[None])) 
X = np.delete(X, 0, 0) 
print("X: ",X) 

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append a NumPy array to a NumPy array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775297/append-a-numpy-array-to-a-numpy-array)

Comment: It would be better to collect your `temp` in a list, and apply the `stack` once at the end.   It is faster than repeated `row_stack`, and doesn't require that extra `empty` and `delete`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to use [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) on 3D extended versions of those arrays -

```
np.vstack((A[None],B[None]))
```

Another way with `np.row_stack` (functionally same as `np.vstack`) -

```
np.row_stack((A[None],B[None]))
```

And similarly with [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) -

```
np.concatenate((A[None],B[None])) # By default stacks along axis=0
```

Another way would be with [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) and specifying the axis of stacking i.e. `axis=0` or skip it as that's the default axis of stacking -

```
np.stack((A,B))
```

Comment: here is my code.
X = np.empty([54, 7])
for seq in train_set:
    print(seq)
    temp = dp.set_xdata(seq)    #make 2d numpy array
    print(temp.shape)
    X = np.row_stack((X[None], temp[None]))
X = np.delete(X, 0, 0)
print("X: ",X)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions.

How can i fixed it?

Comment: @ukDongha What are the shapes of `X` and `temp`? At which line is that error occuring?

Comment: 2d numpy array. and second loop np.row_stack() function is error. i think it is because 3d array + 2d array.

Comment: @ukDongha Well you are making `X` a 3D array at the first iteration of that loop. So, at the second iteration, you are trying to stack that 3D array with a 2D array (temp). Thus, you are seeing the error.

Comment: How can I fix it? How can I append 2d array to 3d array?

Comment: @ukDongha `np.vstack((3D_array, 2D_array[None]))`.

Comment: Excellent! It is perfect! Thank you so much!