# make 2 dimention array by two 1 dimension

Tags: python, numpy

It might be too simple  question though,,

I want to make

from

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
```

to

```
[[1,2,3],
[4,5,6]]
```

`+` ,`concatenate`, `append` neither doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41523942/how-to-append-numpy-arrays)

Comment: What exactly did you try, and what was the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `vstack`:

```
np.vstack([a,b])
```

Or `stack`:

```
np.stack([a,b], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: or `np.array((a,b))` which is essentially `np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])`.