# python plot 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am having a bit of misunderstanding with numpy array
I have a set of two data (m, error) which I would like to plot

I save them in the array like this as I catch them in the same loop (which is probably causing the issue)

```
sum_error = np.append(m,error)
```

Then just simply trying to plot like this but it doesn't work as apparently this array is only of size 1 (with a tuple?)

```
plt.scatter(x=sum_error[:, 0], y=sum_error[:, 1])
```

What is the correct way to proceed? should I really make two different arrays, one for m, one for error in order to plot them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is answered on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775297/append-a-numpy-array-to-a-numpy-array), try using

```
np.vstack((m,error))
```