# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, reshape

I have the following Python script portion:

```
X_to_text_file = np.savetxt('x.txt', X.reshape(np.shape(X)), fmt='%5f')
```

for which I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Provided that `X` is a `Numpy` array, which I obtained as follows:

```
for img in range(len(names)):
    for name in names:
        img = np.array(Image.open(name))
        X.append(img)
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error and how I can solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: The snippet you provided doesn't show how X is defined, only that you append np.array named 'img' *to* it.

Comment: @zencodism Yes, this is exactly how I did it

Comment: X is not a `numpy` array, but just a *vanilla* list. You constructed a list of numpy arrays, not a numpy array itself.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh, so I converted Image to a Numpy array. How can I have those in a Numpy array in this case? Would it also solve the error?

Comment: @Simplicity, can you elaborate? What are you trying to achieve? Are you after reading multiple images into a single numpy array?

Comment: Try `X = np.array(X)` after the loop

Comment: @MaxU Yes, exactly, this is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: `X = np.array([np.array(Image.open(f)) for f in names])`?

Answer (score -1):

I see two problems here. First, your snippet is incomplete, as there is no definition of X. Without it, in minimal example, you'd see something like:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X.append(np.array())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'X' is not defined
```

So, you had to create X somewhere before, and judging by your error message, it's a plain Python list.

Now, on how to join numpy arrays together, I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775297/append-a-numpy-array-to-a-numpy-array) will help you out.