# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am making a model using word2vec. After training the model i was using cosine similarity. But i am getting the following error.
I am using python 3
The code I used is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_distances
cos_dist =[]
cos_dist =[cos_dist]
cos_dist = np.array(cos_dist).reshape(1, -1)
for vec in data[:-1]:
    cos_dist.append(float(cosine_distances(vec,data[-1])))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-14-ef6e7efe7eaa> in <module>
      5 cos_dist = np.array(cos_dist).reshape(1, -1)
      6 for vec in data[:-1]:
----> 7     cos_dist.append(float(cosine_distances(vec,data[-1])))
      8 
      9 

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have such a method. What's the problem here?

Comment: As error says `numpy` array doesn't have any attribute called `append`. You can use `list` to append values

Comment: Don't use `np.append`.  It's hard to use correctly, and slow when used repeatedly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [np.append](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) which doesn't work inplace:

```
cos_dist = np.append(cos_dist, [float(cosine_distances(vec,data[-1]))])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.concatenate(list1, list2)` or `numpy.append()`.

There's a similar discussion in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775297/append-a-numpy-array-to-a-numpy-array)