# How can I properly append a matrix to the bottom of an existing matrix in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, linear-algebra

I have two matrices, A and B. A and B are each 100 x 100. I am trying to produce a combined matrix AB such that is 200 x 100 with the elements of A in the first 100 x 100 and the elements of B in the second 100 x 100.

I tried doing the following, but it says the shape is (2, 1, 500, 500) when I do this in Python.

```
def get_bigAB(n, lamb):
    return np.array([[A], [get_B(n, lamb)]])
```

My entries are floats, not simple integers.

My get_B function performs as expected, and of course, I am using Python 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append a NumPy array to a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775297/append-a-numpy-array-to-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `np.vstack` ended up working. Thanks for helping!

```
def get_Alambda(n, lamb):
    B = get_lambdaI(n, lamb)
    AB = np.vstack((A, B))
    return AB
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [numpy concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
import numpy as np
AB = np.concatenate((A,B),axis=0)
print(AB)
print(AB.shape)
```

Comment: This gets me TypeError: concatenate() got multiple values for argument 'axis' ```  def get_Alambda(n, lamb):
    B = get_lambdaI(n, lamb)
    AB = np.concatenate(A, B, axis = 0)
    return AB                    print(get_Alambda(n = 500, lamb = 10e-06))     ```

Comment: could you provide some more information of what type the matrices are? It would be best to also include your data as in [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `vstack(A, B)` where matrix B is appended to the bottom of matrix A. This will give you the dimensions you want.