# Append output in for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, stored-procedures, append

I am getting errors while using append as follows, how do I rectify this? Thank you

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 17     dest_depth = np.arange(0,max_depth,0.05)
> 18     vel_dd = interp1d(depth_z,vel_line,kind='linear',bounds_error=False,fill_value=n.nan,axis=0)(dest_depth)
> ---> 19     ypred_2D_dd.append(vel_dd)
> 20     z_stack_length.append(len(dest_depth))
> 21     ypred_2D_dd = np.array(ypred_2D_dd)
>
> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

# ypred_2D (1280,251)


#convert to depth domain
n = ypred_2D.shape[1] #number of shots
dt=8e-11
ypred_2D_dd = []
z_stack_length = []
for i in range(n):
    vel_line = ypred_2D[:,i]
    depth_z = np.cumsum(vel_line * dt, axis=0) / 2
    depth_z = np.insert(depth_z[:1280-1],0,0,axis=0)
    max_depth = np.max(depth_z)
    dest_depth = np.arange(0,max_depth,0.05)
    vel_dd = interp1d(depth_z, vel_line,kind='linear',bounds_error=False,fill_value=np.nan,axis=0)(dest_depth)
    ypred_2D_dd.append(vel_dd)
    z_stack_length.append(len(dest_depth))
    ypred_2D_dd = np.array(ypred_2D_dd)
    z_stack_length = np.array(z_stack_length)
    min_z = np.min(z_stack_length)
    vel_dd_img_corr = []
for i in range(n):
    vel_line = ypred_2D_dd[i][:min_z]
    vel_dd_img_corr.append(vel_line)
    vel_dd_img_corr = np.array(vel_dd_img_corr).T
    vel_dd_img_corr[:10,:] = 299792500
    ep_ypred = 299792500**2 / vel_dd_img_corr **2

#save
#sio.savemat('Synthetic/Data/2D/ep_ypred2D.mat',{'ep':ypred_2D_dd})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the code section below may be causing the issue:

```
z_stack_length.append(len(dest_depth))
ypred_2D_dd = np.array(ypred_2D_dd)
z_stack_length = np.array(z_stack_length)
```

As I understand, you want to append an item to the `z_stack_length` variable - But in the following lines, you define `z_stack_length` as a numpy array, which behaves differently than a regular list

Append will only work for ordinary lists, not numpy arrays - You can use either `numpy.concatenate(list1 , list2)` or `numpy.append()`

The thread below may offer some more insight:

[Concatenate a NumPy array to another NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775297/append-a-numpy-array-to-a-numpy-array)