# numpy.ndarray append another numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

```
my_list=[[123.45][34.23][123.98][67]]
```

The type of my_list is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
I need to add a new numpy.ndarray to the existing my_list.

```
new=[34.6]
```

Expected output:

```
my_list=[[123.45][34.23][123.98][67][34.6]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate a NumPy array to another NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775297/concatenate-a-numpy-array-to-another-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0):

please check [concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr2 = np.array([4, 5, 6])

# Append array arr2 to array arr1
c = np.concatenate((arr1, arr2))

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```py
np.append(my_list, new)
```